# VB: Random Shuffler Duplicating Values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to make a Deal or no Deal game, however my problem at the moment is assigning set values to cases randomly. I have had no luck with randomly generating a number and checking if it already exists, so I am now attempting to simply shuffle the array. The problem is, for some reason, values get duplicated.
The code:

```
 Dim nCaseValues(26) As Integer 'The different possible values for a case
    Dim nCaseNumbers(26) As Integer 'The different case numbers

    Dim nShadowNumber As Integer 'This holds the first number in the shuffle
    Dim nShuffleNumber1 As Integer 'The first random position
    Dim nShuffleNumber2 As Integer 'The second random position

    'Clear the list if it already has content
    listArray1.Items.Clear()
    listArray2.Items.Clear()
    listArray3.Items.Clear()

    'Declare array for case values
    nCaseValues(0) = 1500
    nCaseValues(1) = 1
    nCaseValues(2) = 2
    nCaseValues(3) = 5
    nCaseValues(4) = 10
    nCaseValues(5) = 20
    nCaseValues(6) = 50
    nCaseValues(7) = 100
    nCaseValues(8) = 150
    nCaseValues(9) = 200
    nCaseValues(10) = 250
    nCaseValues(11) = 500
    nCaseValues(12) = 750
    nCaseValues(13) = 1000
    nCaseValues(14) = 2000
    nCaseValues(15) = 3000
    nCaseValues(16) = 4000
    nCaseValues(17) = 5000
    nCaseValues(18) = 10000
    nCaseValues(19) = 15000
    nCaseValues(20) = 20000
    nCaseValues(21) = 30000
    nCaseValues(22) = 50000
    nCaseValues(23) = 75000
    nCaseValues(24) = 100000
    nCaseValues(25) = 200000

    'Declare array for case numbers
    For genCaseNumArray = 0 To 25
        nCaseNumbers(genCaseNumArray) = 0
        listArray1.Items.Add(genCaseNumArray)
    Next

'The shuffle
    For J = 0 To 25 'This assigns case values to case numbers (It's probably moot, as I can just use the nCaseValues position, but it's here for now)
        nCaseNumbers(J) = nCaseValues(J)
    Next
    For K = 0 To 25 'Lists the items below, this could possibly be an error

        For I = 0 To 50 'Shuffles the list 50 times
            nShuffleNumber1 = (Int(Rnd() * 26)) 'Gets a random number and assigns it
            nShuffleNumber2 = (Int(Rnd() * 26))'Gets a random number and assigns it
            nShadowNumber = nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber1) 'This holds the first value during the shuffle
            nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber1) = nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber2)'First value now equals second value...
            nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber2) = nShadowNumber 'And now second value holds first value.

        Next 'Lists items in lists objects on the form
        listArray1.Items.Add(K)
        listArray2.Items.Add(nCaseValues(K))
        listArray3.Items.Add(nCaseNumbers(K))
    Next
```

I need each value to be unique. I am pretty sure it is a logic error in my code. Any help on why the numbers are duplicating would be great.

Here are a couple of outputs:

[image: Outcome #1]
[image: Outcome #2]

The first list is the Case Number, second is possible values in order, third is the final outcome - The individual case value. As you can see, some are duplicated, and the first list is repeated twice..
EDIT: I found out why it repeated twice - I was stupid enough to leave another for loop that was also adding to the list. I have solved my problem, see the answer below.

Comment: It is just not the correct way to get a random shuffle.  The way you'd do it with a deck of 52 cards is to first get a random number between 0 and 51.  Take out the corresponding card.  Next get a random number between 0 and 50, take out the card.  Next between 0 and 49.  Etcetera, repeat until the deck is empty.  Google "vb.net fisher yates shuffle", lots of hits.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem (well, more just luck) - the internal For loop *shouldn't* of been internal. I moved it out, and voila - it works like a charm. So far. Let's just wait.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Randomize() 'Make the form random

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'State Variables
    Dim nCaseValues(26) As Integer 'The different possible values for a case
    Dim nShadowNumber As Integer
    Dim nShuffleNumber1 As Integer
    Dim nShuffleNumber2 As Integer

    'Clear the list if it already has content
    listArray1.Items.Clear()
    listArray2.Items.Clear()
    listArray3.Items.Clear()

    'Declare array for case values
    nCaseValues(0) = 1500  'If you're wondering why this is here, it's because I couldn't be bothered to work with a "car" value.
    nCaseValues(1) = 1
    nCaseValues(2) = 2
    nCaseValues(3) = 5
    nCaseValues(4) = 10
    nCaseValues(5) = 20
    nCaseValues(6) = 50
    nCaseValues(7) = 100
    nCaseValues(8) = 150
    nCaseValues(9) = 200
    nCaseValues(10) = 250
    nCaseValues(11) = 500
    nCaseValues(12) = 750
    nCaseValues(13) = 1000
    nCaseValues(14) = 2000
    nCaseValues(15) = 3000
    nCaseValues(16) = 4000
    nCaseValues(17) = 5000
    nCaseValues(18) = 10000
    nCaseValues(19) = 15000
    nCaseValues(20) = 20000
    nCaseValues(21) = 30000
    nCaseValues(22) = 50000
    nCaseValues(23) = 75000
    nCaseValues(24) = 100000
    nCaseValues(25) = 200000

    'Declare array for case numbers, probably obsolete
    For genCaseNumArray = 0 To 25
        nCaseNumbers(genCaseNumArray) = 0
    Next

    For J = 0 To 25 'Assigning case values to case numbers
        nCaseNumbers(J) = nCaseValues(J)
    Next

    For I = 0 To 26  'The main shuffle.
        nShuffleNumber1 = (Int(Rnd() * 26))  'This selects a random number between 0 and 25, somehow.
        nShuffleNumber2 = (Int(Rnd() * 26))  'Ditto
        nShadowNumber = nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber1)  'This "Shadow Number" will be used to temporarily hold the value of the first case
        nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber1) = nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber2)  'The value of the first case now equals the value of the second case...
        nCaseNumbers(nShuffleNumber2) = nShadowNumber  '... and vice versa.

    Next  'Display the cases, case values and shuffled case values in the lists.
    For K = 0 To 25
        listArray1.Items.Add(K)
        listArray2.Items.Add(nCaseValues(K))
        listArray3.Items.Add(nCaseNumbers(K))
    Next
```

I found this to be a really simple and (maybe) efficient way of shuffling an array. A lot easier than writing a script for a MERN.

Answer (score -1):

I used to recommend randomising an array like this:

```
Dim rng As New Random

myArray = myArray.OrderBy(Function(element) rng.NextDouble()).ToArray()
```

It has since been pointed out to me that there is a serious issue with that because it will generate a new random number for the same element multiple times and thus comparing the same two elements could produce different results on different occasions.  There's also the lesser issue that it creates a new array object.  The following overcomes both those issues:

```
Dim rng As New Random
Dim keys = myArray.Select(Function(element) rng.NextDouble()).ToArray()

Array.Sort(keys, myArray)
```

That generates one random number per element and then sorts the original array in-place by those keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - will this give the elements of the array a unique value, though?

Comment: The original array, i.e. `myArray` in the example, will still contain the same values it started with, but they will be in a random order.  The `keys` array will contain random `Double` values that are all >= to 0.0 and < 1.0. They will likely all be unique but not necessarily so. That `keys` array is simply discarded after the `Sort` call because it is no longer required.  It exists purely for the randomisation process.